# How to test my website's forms?

Tags: xss

I wanted to test my website's forms and tried a couple of script string. Then 
I have installed [XSS Me](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/xss-me/) to my Firefox, however, I am still confused about how it works. How do I start testing my website? Or does it test it automatically? If it does, I did not get any reports.

Is there any good tutorial on this plug in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see full documentation on developer site. Also, you can get sources.
See here: http://labs.securitycompass.com/exploit-me/
http://labs.securitycompass.com/exploit-me/xss-me/xss-me-faq/